# Check nested Java objects for null

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have nested JAXB object which I would like to check for null.

```
if(message.getMpiParams() != null & 
        message.getMpiParams().getOne() != null &
        message.getMpiParams().getTwo() != null &
        message.getMpiParams().getThu() != null) { 

        ...// a lot of methods here

    }
```

When the inner object is empty I get always NPE. This is because XML tags are missing. How I can check for missing inner object safely without NPE? I just want to check for null object.

JAXB Object:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "message")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Message{

    @XmlElement(name = "mpi_params")
    public MpiParams mpiParams; 

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MpiParams {

    @XmlElement(name = "one")
    public String one;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "When the inner object is empty I get always NPE."? What inner object? Please show code that will cause an NPE in such a case. The code you show here will only throw NPE if `message` itself is `null`.

Comment: I men when for example inner XML `mpi_params` is missing I get NPE. Post is updated.

Comment: Your null check is fine, your operator usage isn't. See the linked question.

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `&`.

Comment: Is there some way to do this with Java 8 Streams or Otional?

Answer (score -2):

Try changing

if(message.getMpiParams() != null

with

if(!(message.getMpiParams().equals(null))

Comment: When do you expect `.equals(null)` to become true?

Comment: It's OK to perform null checks with !=